# Trying to iterate through columns and delete rows with specific string value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find a way to iterate through each column of a DataFrame and check rows with a specific string and delete them as a pre-processing step for a machine learning exercise. The code I have that manually does this goes as follows:

```
train = train[train.Native_Country != ' ?']
train = train[train.Race != ' ?']
train = train[train.Work_Class != ' ?']
train = train[train.Occupation != ' ?']
train = train[train.Relationship != ' ?']
train = train[train.Sex != ' ?']
train = train[train.Work_Class != ' ?']
train = train[train.Occupation != ' ?']
train = train[train.Education != ' ?']
```

There has to be an easier way to leave out or delete these specific rows per column and I feel like I am overthinking how to do this for loop-if loop.

Comment: Are these all your columns or just the str ones?  Are the `'?'` on the same rows or are they randomly located?

Comment: These '?' are randomly located through some columns. It appears that instead of having null values, they replaced them with question marks randomly throughout the dataset.

Comment: Your problem here is that you will lose a lot of information if you progressively drop rows where '?' You may be better off converting these to `NaN` or filling them perhaps, was this data in a csv? if so you can pass `na_values='?'` to treat those as missing values you can then call `df.dropna()`

Comment: Ahh that is definitely a lot easier as a solution.

The '?' values are sparse. It would drop about 2400 rows how to a total of 33000.

Comment: I suggest passing param `na_values='?'` to `read_csv` or do `df = df.replace('?', np.NaN).dropna()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following off of EdChum's answer, try something like this:

```
 columnsyouwant = ['Native_Country', 'Race', 'Work_Class'....]

 for col in columnsyouwant:
    train[col] = train[col].replace(' ?', None)

 train.dropna(inplace=True) #default is how='any' in axis=0 (rows)
```

Comment: I think `df.replace('?', np.NaN)` should also work depending on the `dtypes`s